# iptfile = args and args[0] or "Python/graminit.c"

Tags: python

I encounter the following codes when I read [cpython/keyword.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/keyword.py)

```
def main():
    import sys, re

    args = sys.argv[1:]
    iptfile = args and args[0] or "Python/graminit.c"
    if len(args) > 1: optfile = args[1]
    else: optfile = "Lib/keyword.py"
```

What does `iptfile = args and args[0] or "Python/graminit.c"` mean?
I could understand `iptfile = args or "Python/graminit.c"`.

Additionally, the modules are imported within `main()` rather than positioned on the top, should I follow this convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This file is almost a sort of [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)) to generate the `kwlist`.  It takes two optional inputs, the grammar and the template, and updates the `kwlist` list.  By default, it writes itself!

To address your specific comments

```
iptfile = args and args[0] or "Python/graminit.c"
```

This is a bit of a poor man's [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) expression.  If `args` is truthy: `iptfile = args[0]`, otherwise `iptfile = "Python/graminit.c"` -- perhaps a more readable form of this would be

```
iptfile = args[0] if args else "Python/graminit.c"
```

Though if you look at [the commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/eb8c972648c9fec8bad5419eb1ab13cafa52d3d8) which introduced this code it predates that syntax even being in the language (1997-03-20)!

The imports are situated inside a function as a sort of *performance hack*.  The code to generate the keyword list file is almost never executed, except at build time and so the imports (which could be costly) are avoided in the critical path.  Generally this style isn't necessary and importing at the top of the file is just fine (and often easier to maintain / collaborate).